# Two way data-binding inside blazor template

Tags: c#, blazor, matblazor

I would like to use a two-way databinding between a component inside a template and its parents. The one way data binding is working well. But when I modified the Context passed from the RenderFragment this modification is not propagate to the template (container). Here is the example.

This it the template definition. We have a form and we want to be able to specify the content of the form in function of the model.

```cs
@typeparam TItem
@typeparam TItemDtoCU
@typeparam TDataService

<EditForm Model="@Item" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" class="item-editor">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    @FormContentTemplate(Item)

    <span class="save">
        <MatButton Type="submit" Raised="true">Save</MatButton>
        <MatButton Type="reset" Raised="true" OnClick="HandleCancelSubmit">Cancel</MatButton>
    </span>
</EditForm>
```

Here is the place where I use this template

```cs
        <ModelEditorTemplate TItem="ClassName"
                             TItemDtoCU="OtherClassName"
                             TDataService="ServiceClassName"
                             ItemId="SelectedItem?.Id"
                             OnItemAdded="ItemAdded"
                             OnItemUpdated="ItemUpdated">

            <FormContentTemplate>
                <span>

                    <MatTextField Label="Name" @bind-Value="context.Name" @bind-Value:event="onchange" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => context.Name)" />
                </span>
            </FormContentTemplate>
        </ModelEditorTemplate>
```

When the user modified the **MatTextField** field is reset to the initial value provided by the template component.

Do you have an idea ?

### Edit 1 : More information about the way we fetched the data

Yes the TDataService is fetching the component from a REST Api. Here the partial class linked to the template :

```
    public partial class ModelEditorTemplate<TItem, TItemDtoCU, TDataService> : ParentThatInheritsFromComponentBase
        where TItem : BaseEntity, new()
        where TDataService : ICrudService<TItem, TItemDtoCU>
    {
        public TItem Item = new TItem();
        [Inject]
        protected TDataService DataService { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
             //...
             await LoadItem();
             // ...
        }

        protected async Task LoadItem()
        {
            //...
            Item = await DataService.Get(ItemId.Value);
            // ....
        }
}
```

Comment: If you remove `@bind-Value:event="onchange"` does it help?

Comment: No, at the beginning it wasn't there. I tried to add it to solve the issue ^^

Comment: How doe the ModelEditorTemplate retrieve the data? Something to do with the TDataService supplied? Can you show us how the MET component queries that service?

Comment: More information in the post, is it enough ?

Comment: Think I got the same question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142096/blazor-editcontext-doesnt-trigger-fieldstate . Already put a bounty on it, but no results.

Comment: If you put some logging in the LoadItem method where it fetches the data from the API - how many times does that get called during the full cycle of Render/Update Name/Re-Render ? How are you checking that the modification has propagated to the MET?

Comment: @MisterMagoo you were right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the field inside `FormContentTemplate` RenderFragment update the model, it triggers the `OnParametersSetAsync` method of the template ,which fetch again the data from the server, update the model and then overwrite the modification done by the user.

There was no issue, with the form input inside the template just bad understanding of how it works.

I corrected the problem by using the `SetParametersAsync` to check if the parameter that change was the one, I was looking for and not the RenderFragment. The `ItemId` is the id of the record, I fetch from the DataService.

```
        public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            _hasIdParameterChange = false;

            if(parameters.TryGetValue(nameof(ItemId), out int? newItemIdValue))
            {
                _hasIdParameterChange = (newItemIdValue != ItemId);
            }

            await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
        }
```